# javascript datapicker restrict dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this code to restrict various "datepicker dates".  :

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    })({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    $(".datepicker").datepicker;
});

var calcDate = function() {
    var start = $('#conference_date_in').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#conference_date_out').datepicker('getDate');
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

    document.getElementById('total_days').value = days;
}

$('#conference_date_out').change(calcDate);
({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });

$('#conference_date_in').change(calcDate);
</script>
```

Is my min/max date in the wrong section?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set mindate and max date like this

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
```

[Example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/min-max.html)

Reference: [mindate and maxdate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate)

And if you want to disable a specific date range you can use the following code

```
//  unavailable dates range
var dateRange = ["2012/05/20","2012/05/29"]; // yyyy/MM/dd


function unavailable(date) {
    var startDate = new Date(dateRange[0]);
    var endDate = new Date(dateRange[1]);
    var day = date.getDay();



    if(date > startDate && date < endDate )
        return [false, "disabled"];
    else if(day > 0 && day < 6)
        return [true, "enabled"];
    else 
        return [false, "disabled"];

}

$('#iDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: unavailable });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/jPUBv/3/)

Comment: thank you.  I adjusted the code, and it seems to be working, except now my "dateformat" ddmmyy - is no longer working?   also, i have now been able to limit the user from selecting dates in the past for conference start and end, but how would i prevent the "conference end date" from being before the begin date?            '$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+100M +10D" })({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    })({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    
});'